# User defined error does not get printed

Tags: node.js, error-handling

```
axios.get(geocodeUrl).then((response) =>
{
  if(response.data.status === 'ZERO_RESULTS')
  {
    throw new ERROR('Unable To Find That Address');
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data, undefined ,2));
}).catch((e)=> {
  if(e.code === 'ENOTFOUND')
  {
    console.log('Unable to contact api servers');
  }
  else {
    console.log(e.message);
    console.log("xyz");
  }
});
```

It prints :

`"Error is not defined"`

instead of

`"Unable to find that address"`. 
`xyz` gets printed.

Comment: Change `ERROR` to `Error`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have done a syntactical error i.e. `ERROR` should not be written in UpperCase it should be like `Error`. That's why it is not recognizing the `Error` keyword.

So the correction is in this line:

```
throw new Error('Unable To Find That Address');
```

Answer (score -1):

You must not have made jQuery available to your script.

Add this to the top of your file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Seriously, what does this have to do with the OP problem. It's clearly tagged in node.js and even if it wasn't what does jQuery have to do with: `Error`